# D3: How to stop child nodes from being attracted towards the center when parent is dragged in force-directed tree?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have built a force-directed tree layout using d3.js v7. It works fine so far except for a behavior that I've seen even in the examples on Observable https://observablehq.com/collection/@d3/d3-force

This is what I have so far.

[image]

The behavior is that when I drag a node towards the edge, the children seem to be attracted towards the center. Like so:

[image]

I'd like, instead, for the child nodes of "Load Balancing" to appear like this:

[image]

Here is how I've set up the simulation:

```
const simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .force(
    "link",
    d3
      .forceLink()
      .id((d) => d.id)
      .distance(100)
      .strength(1)
  )
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force("x", d3.forceX())
  .force("y", d3.forceY())
  .alphaDecay(0.05);

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link
      .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);
  
    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  });
```

I've created a working Codepen for this [here](https://codepen.io/davidaik/pen/rNdxOzM) for you to play around with what I'm talking about.

I've tried changing the node and link forces to different values but they didn't really help. I've also tried disabling the `center` force but then the simulation never appears on the screen if I do that.

```
.force("center").strength(0)
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

One way to control the other nodes behavior is to fix them in the dragged function.  I have added a function in your code, to fix other nodes and not allow them to move during drag.

```js
const data = {
  name: "AWS",
  resourceType: "aws",
  children: [{
    name: "VPC",
    resourceType: "vpc",
    children: [{
      name: "Load Balancing",
      resourceType: "load-balancing",
      children: [{
          name: "Public subnet 1",
          resourceType: "subnet"
        },
        {
          name: "Public subnet 2",
          resourceType: "subnet"
        },
        {
          name: "Private subnet 1",
          resourceType: "subnet"
        },
        {
          name: "Private subnet 2",
          resourceType: "subnet"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
};

// Set up the canvas
const chartContainer = d3.select("#svgcontainer");
const containerWidth = Math.max(
  1200,
  chartContainer.node().getBoundingClientRect().width
);

const containerHeight = Math.max(
  600,
  chartContainer.node().getBoundingClientRect().height
);

const margin = {
    top: 24,
    right: 124,
    bottom: 24,
    left: 24
  },
  width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = chartContainer
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height]);

const gLinks = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "#999")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6);

// Prepare the data
const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
let node, link;

// Deeper descendants are collapsed by default
root.descendants().forEach((d, i) => {
  d.id = i;
  d._children = d.children;
  if (d.depth > 2) d.children = null;
});

// Set up the force simulation
const simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .force(
    "link",
    d3
    .forceLink()
    .id((d) => d.id)
    .distance(100)
    .strength(1)
  )
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force("x", d3.forceX())
  .force("y", d3.forceY())
  .alphaDecay(0.05);

// Update =========================================================
function update() {
  const links = root.links();
  const nodes = root.descendants();

  // Set up nodes
  node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes, function(d) {
    return d.id;
  });
  node.exit().remove();

  const nodeEnter = node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(drag(simulation));

  nodeEnter
    .append("circle")
    .attr("fill", (d) => {
      return "#fff";
    })
    .attr("r", 16);

  nodeEnter
    .append("text")
    .attr("dx", 32)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    });

  nodeEnter.on("click", onNodeClicked);
  node = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Set up links
  link = gLinks.selectAll(".link").data(links, function(d) {
    return d.target.id;
  });
  link.exit().remove();
  const linkEnter = link.enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");
  link = linkEnter.merge(link);

  simulation.nodes(nodes);
  simulation.force("link").links(links);
}

function drag(simulation) {
  function dragstarted(event) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
    event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;

    event.fx = event.subject.x;
    event.fy = event.subject.y;
  }

  function dragged(event) {
    event.subject.fx = event.x;
    event.subject.fy = event.y;
    event.fx = event.x;
    event.fy = event.y;
    fix_other_nodes(event.subject);
  }

  function dragended(event) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    event.subject.fx = event.x;
    event.subject.fy = event.y;

  }

  function fix_other_nodes(this_node) {
    node.each(function(d) {
      if (this_node != d) {
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
      }
    });
  }

  return d3
    .drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended);
}

function onNodeClicked(event, d) {
  // Show details drawer
  // setIsDrawerOpen(true);
  if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  } else {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  }

  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach((n) => {
      n.fx = d.x;
      n.fy = d.y;

      // Needed to make the children radiate from the parent upon expanding.
      n.needToUnfix = true;
    });
  }

  update();

  simulation.restart();
}

update();

simulation.on("tick", () => {
  link
    .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
    .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
    .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
    .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    if (d.needToUnfix) {
      // This is used to make the expanding children radiate from the parent.
      d.x = d.fx;
      d.y = d.fy;

      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
      d.needToUnfix = false;
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});
```

```css
/************************/

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}

.App {
  height: 100%;
}

#svgcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.node {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 4px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.4));
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.resource-icon {
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.box-details {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.box-details text {
  font: 8px sans-serif;
}

.reset-zoom-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-MefNfAGJ/pEy89xLOFs3V6pYPs6AmUhXJrRlydI/9wZuGrqxmrdQ80zKHUcyadAcpH67teDZcBeS6oMJLPtTqw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div className="App">
  <div id="svgcontainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. However, this behavior isn't quite what I'm looking for. I need the children of a node that is being dragged to come along with that node without those child nodes being attracted towards the center. I've illustrated the desired behavior in my question.